# How programmatically get field value from fallback language when field level fallback is enabled?

Tags: language-fallback

I'm using sitecore 9.3. I set `en` as fallback language for `en-IE`. I have enabled **field level fallback** on the template level.

I have item with 2 fields. For `en-IE`:

- Text_1 - is empty, so value from `en` is displayed
- Text_2 - has value "Text_2 en-IE"

[image: field fallback value]

How can I get fallback value for *Text_1* field? All solutions I have found are related to item level fallback and involve using `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.GetFallbackItem()` to get whole fallback item, however in my case I have only one field with fallback value and above method returns `null`.

I have tried different combinations of `field.GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue, bool allowFallbackValue, bool allowInheritValue, bool allowInnerValue)`:

```
Language lang = Language.Parse("en-IE");
Item item_ = master.GetItem("DE0A175C-AB8B-4521-874D-10C7F3F6943C", lang);
Field text_1_field = item_.Fields["Text_1"];
bool contains_fallback_value = text_1_field.ContainsFallbackValue;
string value = text_1_field.Value;
string value_1 = text_1_field.GetValue(false, false, true);
string value_2 = text_1_field.GetValue(false, false, true, false, false);
string value_3 = text_1_field.GetValue(true, true, true, true);
```

but I haven't got correct field value:

- `contains_fallback_value` equals `false`
- `value` equals `""`
- `value_1` equals `null`
- `value_2` equals `null`
- `value_3` equals `""`

Shouldn't `value` store value from fallback language (i.e. `Text`) and `contains_fallback_value` be `true`? How can I get fallback value for this field?

Comment: Not exactly. Link you have provided is about item level fallback. I use field level fallback.

Comment: Try forcefully field.GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue, bool allowFallbackValue, bool allowInheritValue, bool allowInnerValue)  get the allowFallbackValue and see if you can get the correct value

Comment: @YogeshSharma, you mean get field value using field.GetValue(false, false, true, false, false)? It returns null

Comment: `(true, true, true, true)` would be the call. But in reality you will get your field value by just going `item["field name"]`. There is never a need to call `ReadAll()` for any scenario outside perhaps serialization.

Comment: @MarkCassidy, thank you for your answer. `(true,  true,  true, true)` returned `""`

Comment: ![Untitled.png](https://postimg.cc/nM4MSb6H)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding below code while retrieving field value.

```
using (new LanguageFallbackFieldSwitcher(true))
 {
   // Retrieving Item's Field Value
 }
```

Also make sure the database do not contains any entry for the item in the fields table. You can check for the corresponding entry in the db by executing below SQL Query:

```
Select * from {{db_name.FieldsTable}}
Where ItemId = '{{item_id}}' and Language = '{{language}}' and FieldId = '{{fieldid}}'
```

In case the entry is there you need to delete that and check that again. This is because fallback value is returned only when value in the field is not changed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It worked. `text_1_field.Value` returned fallback value and `text_1_field.ContainsFallbackValue` was `true`.

Comment: One more question. In DB I see 3 tables associated with fields: `VersionedFields`, `UnversionedFields`, `ArchivedFields`. By `FieldsTable` you mean `VersionedFields` table?

Comment: ya it depends on the field type you are using..If the field is shared it will be present in SharedFields table, in case the field is versioned it will be there on VersionedFields table and lastly if the field is unversioned it will be there on UnVersionedFields table. 
you can search by the field id's in these table and  delete those rows which have empty value and restart the CMS for the fallback changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not able to get the fallback value using `field.GetValue(bool allowStandardValue, bool allowDefaultValue, bool allowFallbackValue, bool allowInheritValue, bool allowInnerValue)`,  I have implemented a workaround.

```
Language lang = Language.Parse("en-IE");
Item item = master.GetItem("DE0A175C-AB8B-4521-874D-10C7F3F6943C", lang);
Field text_1_field = item.Fields["Text_1"];

if (text_1_field.HasValue == false)
{
    Item itemTemplate = master.GetItem(item.TemplateID, item.Language);
    
    Item templateField = itemTemplate.Children[text_1_field.SectionDisplayName].Children[text_1_field.Name];
    
    if (templateField.Fields["Enable Shared Language Fallback"].Value == "1" || templateField.Fields["Enable Language Fallback"].Value == "1")
    {
        //Field level fallback enabled
        Language fallbackLanguage = Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageFallbackManager.GetFallbackLanguage(item.Language, master, item.ID);
        Item fallbackItem = master.GetItem(item.ID, fallbackLanguage);
        String fieldValue = fallbackItem.Fields[text_1_field.Name].Value;
        
        //Further logic
    }
    else
    {
        //Field level fallback disabled
        
        //Further logic
    }

}
```